# Dynamic add new panel to bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, append, bootstrap-accordion

I write a function to dynamic add new panel to bootstrap accordion
and it work

My problem is the panel body show inverted 
See the image below
[image]

And when i try the same code in jsfiddle it work fine 
https://jsfiddle.net/Eadhassan/aqpbzcex/1/

This is my HTML code :

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block addPanel" type="button">Add panel</button>
<div class="panel-group panels" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false"></div>
```

This is my jQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addPanel').click(function() {
        var x = $('.panels .panel').length+1;
        var template = '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
        template += '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">';
        template += '<h4 class="panel-title">';
        template += '<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#' + x + '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Panel ' + x + '</a>';
        template += '<a id="removeSlide" style="cursor: pointer" class="pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete this"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></a>';
        template += '</h4></div>';
        template += '<div id="' + x + '" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel"><div class="panel-body">';

        // Title
        template += '<div class="form-group">';
        template += '<div class="row">';
        template += '<label class="form-label col-md-5" for="slideTitle">title</label>';
        template += '<div class="col-md-7">';
        template += '<input type="text" name="sliderSource[' + x + '][slideTitle]" id="slideTitle" class="form-control">';
        template += '</div></div></div>';

        // Description
        template += '<div class="form-group">';
        template += '<div class="row">';
        template += '<label class="form-label col-md-5" for="slideTitle">Description</label>';
        template += '<div class="col-md-7">';
        template += '<textarea name="sliderSource[' + x + '][slideTitle]" id="slideTitle" class="form-control"></textarea>';
        template += '</div></div></div>';

        // Close open tags
        template += '</div></div></div>';

        $('.panels').append( template );
    });
</script>
```

Any body had this problem before

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vo1npqdx/821/ .. check for rotate on css or something like that

Comment: and me to :) , when i try the same code in Codepen it work fine with me [link](https://codepen.io/EadHassan/pen/VbEdGb)

Comment: That mean the posted code works good .. try to check `.panel-body` class on your css may be the problem is there

Comment: Ok ya Ead copy/paste your css code to your Codepen and let's see what is going on

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef the same code work fine if i write it in HTML page but when i append it using jQuery it shown inverted, i don't know where is the problem

Comment: What can I do? *Eh el 7al ba2a??*  .. final attempt .. try to unlink all css stylesheet even the bootstrap one and try again

Comment: Perfect solution, it's work fine when i unlink the theme css files. Now i can using inspect element to find the problem. Thank you @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: *tab el 7amdullah wenaby fra7teny :-)*  You're welcome, Have a great day :-)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I gut it, i write a custom css role to .panel-collapse

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem
it was in css file a role for rotate collapse button
many thanks for @Mohamed-Yousef